Failure running "docker compose" building aks-store-demo following Azure AKS turtorial
I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app?tabs=azure-cli, deploying aks-store-demo in Azure AKS.
I've finished step1, 2, which was to clone the sample application to my own local VM running RHEL9.2.
The step 3 "docker compose -f docker-compose-quickstart.yml up -d" got failure with outputs as below:
[jie@hostname aks-store-demo]$ sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-quickstart.yml up -d
[+] Building 355.4s (7/9)                                                                                                       docker:default
[+] Building 1464.1s (8/9)                                                                                                      docker:default
 => [order-service internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 693B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [order-service internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.20.4-alpine                                                     31.8s
 => [order-service internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 127B                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [order-service 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:18.20.4-alpine@sha256:17514b20acef0e79691285e7a59f3ae561f7a1702a9adc72a515aef23f3267  0.0s
 => [order-service internal] load build context                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.45kB                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [order-service 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [order-service 3/5] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [order-service 4/5] RUN npm install --production                                                                             1432.2s
------
 > [order-service 4/5] RUN npm install --production:
0.599 npm warn config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
399.5 npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
426.8 npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
1272.3 npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
1432.0 npm notice
1432.0 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.2
1432.0 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
1432.0 npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2
1432.0 npm notice
1432.0 npm error code ETIMEDOUT
1432.0 npm error syscall read
1432.0 npm error errno -110
1432.1 npm error network read ETIMEDOUT
1432.1 npm error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
1432.1 npm error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
1432.1 npm error network
1432.1 npm error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
1432.1 npm error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
1432.1
1432.1 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-12T01_35_55_794Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install --production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 146

The output said "A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-12T01_35_55_794Z-debug-0.log" but actually the /root/.npm/_logs/ doesn't exist.
The npm(10.7.0) was already installed.
It looks like a problem of network connection. This VM running "docker compose" is located in China.
Kindly could you please advise?

I'm bringing update.
I executed 2 commands as below:

npm cache clean --force
npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com

Then re-ran "sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-quickstart.yml up -d", it was success.
Most likely the 2nd command which is to set a mirror of npm works.
